# Firebase realtime database filtering data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so here i have 
[image: Structure]

So I am making dating app, and now i come to the moment, where i need to create a list of people to match with for user.

So I need a firebase query to look in to gender and check if the people already matched, if yes it should not be included in the list.

I tried, filtering data by gender. How I should edit this query to check if they already matched?
Matches are displayed in **users/{userID}/matches/{matchedUserID}**

This is what i tried:

```
async createUserListAndNavigate() {
    let genderTolook = 'female';

    let data = firebase
      .database()
      .ref('users/')
      .orderByChild('gender')
      .equalTo(genderTolook);
    data.once('value', snapshot => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `array-contains-any` query to check if the matches array already contains the user_id.

```
var users = db.collection("users");
users.where('tempuser.matches', 'array-contains-any', [<USER_ID_TO_MATCH>]);
```

Based on the result you can make further queries/operations. You could also combine this query with other queries.
See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) for further details.

Comment: you writed 'tempuser.matches' there will be many users so how should this part be eddited? And I am using REALTIME database not Cloud Firestore

Comment: You will get all users as a result whose matches arrays contain USER_ID_TO_MATCH

Comment: Ohh yes you are right, I have the data, now I can play with it on user side.